# How to reduce python fft output

Tags: python, numpy, fft

I'm coming from a C# implementation of fft in cscore where I can say that I want the size of my Fourier transform to by 4096. I'm trying to do do a FFT in python now but the size of the Fourier transform is larger(3.8 million). How do I limit this to 4096?

Code I have now

```
1 import numpy as np
2 from scipy.io import wavfile
3 
4 sample_location = r'C:\Users\g\Desktop\Samples'
5 samplerate, data = wavfile.read(sample_location + r"\g_abc.wav")
6
7 fft_data = np.fft.fft(data)
8 freq = np.fft.fftfreq(data.size)
```

At the moment `fft_data.size` is the same size as `data.size`. I want to get a size of 4096

Comment: Could you specify the 2nd argument `n`? https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fft.fft.html

Comment: The output of a DFT is always the size number as the input, you can't change that. What you could do is only use 4096 samples and compute the FFT of those. If you do this repeatedly while moving through your data, you get what is called a [spectrogram](http://stft.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Comment: @Moberg I already tried that, but then I get a MemoryError